# Stop Observable from loop

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

Recently I have been working on RxJava 2 and I have tested the **Observable.interval()**

```
subscription = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

subscription.subscribe(new Observer<Long>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Long aLong) {
                //binding.appBar.mainContent.msg.setText(aLong+"");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {

            }
        });
```

Observable is started after activity's `onCreate` method. And I am logging the output through `onNext()` method. And I have a Stop Button. When it is triggered I want to stop subscription flow.

Even after the stop button is clicked the log keeps on going.

```
stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (subscription != null) {
                    subscription.unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Reading the javadoc of the methods you call will help quite a bit.

Answer (score 3):

You have subscribed with an `Observer`, which means you have to keep a reference to the actual `Disposable` from `onSubscribe(Disposable)` callback, and later perform [`Disposable#dispose()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/disposables/Disposable.html#dispose()) on that object.

```
    private Disposable disposable;

    ...

    Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(
            new Observer() {
              @Override public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                disposable = d;
              }

            // other callbacks here

            });

    disposable.dispose();
```

Instead you can change your subscription to following:

```
    Disposable disposable = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Consumer() {
          @Override public void accept(Long aLong) throws Exception {
            // onNext
          }
        }, new Consumer() {
          @Override public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
            // onError
          }
        }, new Action() {
          @Override public void run() throws Exception {
            // onComplete
          }
        });

    disposable.dispose();
```

Comment: Error:(77, 33) error: cannot find symbol method unsubscribe()

Comment: Error:(77, 33) error: cannot find symbol method cancel()